# Using the environment variables in Angular 2 does not yield expected results

Tags: angular

When we do, `ng serve --env=prod`, shouldn't it work with the values set in the environment.prod.ts? Well, In my case, it does not: I always get the environment.ts values! ( which is the dev version as you know )

I've brought in all relevant sections which I think what matters when it comes to using the environment variables in Angular 2+.

Could you point me if I missed any?

---

main.ts

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
} // if I run enableProdMode();
```

environment.ts

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false, 
  serverBasePath: '',  
};
```

environment.prod.ts

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true, 
  serverBasePath: '/mySubFolder',  
};
```

component.ts

```js
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';
...
this.serverBasePath = environment.serverBasePath;
```

And finally, just to cover our base...

angular-cli.json

```js
...
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use:

```
ng serve --environment=prod
```

or

```
ng serve -e=prod
```

read [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve#options) for possible options with the `ng serve` command

Comment: For a moment, you really got me excited. But this makes no diff. Even though the docs do say and make it appear as if those 2 are the only ones, it is not true. --env is also a valid option. I know that because If I use --env or --environment, cli does not complain but say if I do --enx, it tells me that it does not recognize it.

Comment: what version of the cli are you using? And is `enableProdMode` working and `serverBasePath` not.. or both not?

Comment: good questions.  version is 1.2.1. As to the enableProdMode, here is what I can tell you about it. if I run the enableProdMode outside the never matching if condition, then serverBasePath still nada but but isDevMode() function of ( import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core'; ) outputs FALSE. But,  If we do not force the enableProdMode at the main.ts, it outputs TRUE.There is something totally fishy about this whole thing. I'm gonna move on with checking the location.href.url and then decide whether I'm on the localHost or out there on the server. This is the moment to bite the bullet for me,

Comment: @AverageJoe that version is more than half a year old. Most likely updating to the latest version will resolve it

Comment: most likely you are right... I just did not want to do it in the midst of crunch time... you know, major changes like that may throw all kinds of weirdo situations...  and there is also that local vs global cli stuff that always get  me. I already got 400mg ibuprofen for environment.prod.ts :)

Comment: perhaps for next time try to update dependencies a bit quicker ;) saves the hassle of buying painkillers. Anyways, it's also possible to not have a global `angular-cli` running, and let everything depend on the local one